# A situation when you do too many thing but achieve nothing

Tags: nouns, synonyms

I am looking for few nouns describing "a situation when one does too many things but achieve nothing important or useful".

Comment: I doubt if you can find nouns which describe this, but there may be a few phrases that do.

Comment: Example? Certainly you want to apply that word to a very specific situation. So do describe it. Otherwise there are a million terms that might be applicable, but most actually *won't* be applicable in your case.

Comment: Seems related to me: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101152/are-there-popular-english-sayings-to-express-big-fuss-tiny-result

Comment: @J.R. could be related to many things. [An idiom meaning someone's doing something useless and has no result at the end](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/64079/), [Idiom to describe something that has little to no effect](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/90853/), [An alternative analogy to “beating a dead horse”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/74810/), [A good phrase for “refining a process which is hopelessly broken”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/66303/), [Phrase or idiom for funnelling efforts in wrong direction](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/39726/)...

Comment: @RegDwighт: I agree, and was thinking the same thing. I looked up **futility** in the thesaurus, and found *fruitlessness, pointlessness, uselessness, vanity, ineffectiveness, inefficacy; failure, barrenness, unprofitability; impotence, hollowness, emptiness, forlornness, hopelessness* – words that might answer the O.P.'s question, or describe our attempts to suggest a "right" answer to it.

Comment: Looking at the answers so far, I have to bring the hammer down. @Shan, you will have to clarify, otherwise this is not helping anyone, and least of all yourself.

Comment: This is not the same as http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101152/are-there-popular-english-sayings-to-express-big-fuss-tiny-result because there is no "fuss" involved.  I am voting to re-open and can think of at least one idiom that is suitable for the OP's request.

Answer (score 1):

If there's some resource shared between many targets/users in a way that each of them is short on it, you spread [the resource] thin over too many [targets].

In this case *You spread your time thin over too many tasks.*

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the expression *spinning your wheels*.

```
Example: They're on the grind spinning their wheels.
```

You can also invent your own expressions such as:

```
Circling around in circles (suggesting no movement or direction inspite of activity)

They're pushing too hard, a door that needs pulling.

Or they're pulling what needs pushing.

They're pushing a brick wall.

They're busy chewing the stones.

They're busy chewing the rocks.

They're taking one step forward and two steps back.

They're trying to fleece leather out of a sheep.

They're working hard counting the hairs on their own heads.

They're making about turns to get there.
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be exactly what you want, but a word in roughly the same semantic area is *counterproductive*.