# Can you say “hyperbolizing”?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, hyperbole, antimeria

When you are expressing something in an exaggerated and ironic way, often to prove a point, can you say that you are *hyperbolizing*? Could it be used in a way where you could end the statement with it?  For example: “No, I'm just hyperbolizing (but there’s some truth to it)”.

Any synonyms for this?

> **hyperbolic**
>
> 2 (of language) deliberately exaggerated.

(Oxford Dictionary)

Comment: Since it's in the [dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hyperbolize), I don't see why not.

Comment: To [exaggerate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exaggerate) is a perfectly suitable verb for this purpose, I think.

Comment: I hyperbolize all the time, but I always say _{I'm / I was} being hyperbolic_. I don't like the sound of _I'm hyperbolizing_. Strictly a style choice.

Comment: I rather like the ring of “Of course, I hyperbolise…”!  It’s a rare word, as @Barrie’s answer points out; but since its construction is so transparent, being rare won’t make it obscure to people.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek *Exaggerate* and *hyperbolize* are entirely different things. You for instance, might accuse me of *exaggerating* in the preceding sentence; to which I would respond, "No, I'm *hyperbolizing*, rhetorically overstating my case in order to impress upon citizen that there is some difference between the two.

Comment: @StoneyB So hyperbolization is always exaggeration, but exaggeration may well not be hyperbolization, because the latter  is limited to the rhetoric context, is it that, what you are trying to tell me?

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek  More or less. If you say that "So-and-so's approach *exaggerates* the importance of such-and-such factor", you are accusing So-and-so of (possibly inadvertent) misrepresentation", but not of (possibly venial) hyperbole. --And *exaggerate* may be transitive, while *hyperbolize* may not.

Comment: @BillFranke  I detest both uses with a passion I cannot contain - but I *hyperbolize*.

Comment: @StoneyB MW lists "hyperpolize" as both intransitive and transitive, too. And I fail to understand why it shouldn't.

Comment: @StoneyB: I suppose you could say "But I embellish (for {emphasis / oomph})".

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek  Hmm...I'm showing my age. This use appears to emerge in the late 80s. A hasty Google suggests, however, that MW's sense -roughly, "express X in exaggerated terms" - is rare. The usual modern transitive sense, in both scholarly and vernacular contexts, appears to be "invest X with deliberately exaggerated significance". ... But the field of reference is still essentially rhetorical.

Comment: @StoneyB Then I'm showing mine, too: I learned English in school from about 1988, so if your observation is right, the usage may have widened well before I first encountered the word.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek: *Exaggerating* would work okay in my context, but I think *exaggerate* is lacking that extra dimension of it being sort of ironic and rhetorical to prove a point.

Comment: Also see uses of *hyperbolizing* in  [Meaning of “hyperbole” in “were prone to hyperbole”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80071) and  [Is there a word, preferably a verb, that means to exaggerate a point, or idea, to the detriment of the point?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63269),

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can. The verb *hyperbolize* has been so used since the end of the sixteenth century, although the OED says it is now rare.

Comment: Where does it say it's rare? [OED: hyperbolic](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hyperbolic).

Comment: @citizen -- "hyperbolic" has other connotations in mathematics, science, and engineering. *That* usage is not rare, and rather quite common. The verb form, "hyperbolize," is much rarer, and I've never seen it used in the context of math, etc.

Comment: @citizen: It's not _hyperbolic_ that's rare, but _hyperbolize_, and _hyperbolic_ is in any case an adjective. By the way, your link is not to the OED. The OED requires subscription: http://www.oed.com/

Comment: Actually, in my experience, *hyperbolic* (used in the sense related to *hyperbole*) is exceedingly rare. Much rarer than the use of *hyperbolize*. Maybe this is an American thing. But I would say *hyperbole* is most common, *hyperbolize* is less common but still not rare, and *hyperbolic* is just plain rare. Yes, they are all different parts of speech, but the point is you can construct your phrasing to use any of those, and I find "you're hyperbolizing* much more common than *you're being hyperbolic*.

Comment: My above comment was from personal experience; I now also have a bit of independent support. See edit to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Can you say “hyperbolizing”?

Yes, you can, but it would always be being done "for effect". The usage would be well enough understood by many people but it is extremely unusual.

To do so in a formal context would be unwise as what my be an attempt at humour could well be mistaken for an unsuccessful attempt to appear erudite.

A [Google](http://www.google.com) search returns the following results:

hyperbolizing - 24,300 hits
 hyperbolising - 12,300 hits

both counts indicate minor use only, but enough to suggest a reasonable level of understanding of the term if it was used.

---

Google N Gram - ing is useful, but adding a few more comparison terms adds perspective.

http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=being+hyperbolic%2Chyperbolizing%2Coverstating%2Cexaggerating&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=0

[or smoother](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=being+hyperbolic%2Chyperbolizing%2Coverstating%2Cexaggerating&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=10)

Adding "overstating" and "exaggerating" buries "hyperbolizing" and "being hyperbolic" in the noise. ie the use may have increased in absolute terms, in recent decades, but it is still very rare. It would be interesting to know what influence using Google Books as a reference source has on the result.

[image]

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. If the reader would feel like I'm trying show off or whatever. I want a fairly neutral word for this. We have a great word for it in Swedish. With English though, I can only read the definitions in the dictionary, but never have an idea of how the word actually "feels".

Comment: Please add a link to the stats

Comment: Sure, *hyperbolizing* is rare compared to *exaggerating*. But is it so rare as to warrant **special mention of its rarity** in a dictionary? If OED doesn't mention that *hyperbolic* (in the sense related to hyperbole) is rare, then why should *hyperbolize* be specifically pointed out as rare? My contention is that the OED is outdated regarding *hyperbolize*.

Answer (score 2):

To amplify Peter Shor's comment:  For all I can tell, this is a perfectly normal, acceptable, and not unusually rare word.  I don't have any citations to refute the claim that "this is now rare" but I can say that I hear this word reasonably frequently, and common dictionaries such as [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hyperbolize) (same link given by Peter Shor) and my American Heritage (dead-tree volume) don't mention anything about obsolescence or rarity or indeed anything cautionary at all.  Frankly, I don't see any reason to avoid this word, even for formal use.

**Edit:** OK, I now have something more than my personal experience to share regarding the relative rarity of *hyperbolize*. According to [this Google n-gram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=being+hyperbolic%2Chyperbolizing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), *hyperbolizing* in recent times has been pretty strongly beating out *being hyperbolic*. (Which should come as no surprise, because *hyperbolize* is a more compact but no less clear way to express the idea.) Also, notice the sharp rise in use from about the 1970s. For about a century before that, it was indeed moribund; perhaps the OED is simply several decades behind the times.

Comment: We should let the OED know about "this is now rare", and while at it, audioenglish (http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83852/can-you-say-hyperbolizing/83856#83856) as well.

Answer (score -2):

It is more common to say *use hyperbole*, not *hyperbolize*.

Perhaps it has to do with the fact that we are referring to the particular literary/ rhetoric device called *hyperbole*.

[Familiarity information: HYPERBOLIZE used as a verb is very rare.](http://www.audioenglish.net/dictionary/hyperbolize.htm)